# Vanilla js when key press up and down, change active class

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i press the up and down keys, i want the selected "div" element to change. How can i achieve this. pressing the down key on the keyboard, the selection needs to go to a bottom line.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { // <-- add this wrapper
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

    if (element) {
    
      element.forEach(function(el, key){
        
         el.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log(key);
         
            el.classList.toggle("active");
            
             element.forEach(function(ell, els){
                 if(key !== els) {
                     ell.classList.remove('active');
                 }
                  console.log(els);
             });
         });
      });
    }
});
```

```css
.element{
  background: gray;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}

.element.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

For selecting the element, I would suggest using a single function (`setSelected` in the example), then you can more easily set the active element, whether it be from a click, a keydown, or another call.
Besides that, you don't spread the logic over several places, in case you want something extra to happen when an element becomes active.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { // <-- add this wrapper
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

    if (elements) {    
      let selected = -1;
      
      function setSelected(index){ //single entry point for selecting an element
        if(selected===index)return;
        const activeClass = 'active';
        if(selected >=0)elements[selected].classList.remove(activeClass);
        elements[selected = index].classList.add(activeClass);
      }
      
      elements.forEach((el, index) => el.onclick = e=>setSelected(index));
      document.body.onkeydown  = e=>{ 
        if(selected < 0)return; //no element selected yet
        let i = selected;
        const key = e.key;
        if(key==='ArrowDown')
          i++;
        else if(key==='ArrowUp')
          i--;
        else return false;
        
        setSelected(i = Math.max(0,Math.min(elements.length-1,i)));
        e.preventDefault();
        return true;
      };
    }
});
```

```css
.element{
  background: gray;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}

.element.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass in the array length to the listener function. If you have that function return a new function (a closure) you can keep a note of the the current element index, and compare it to 0 or the length of the array. And because you keep a record of the current index you don't need to loop over *all* the elements to remove the active class, just remove the class from the element you're on, and add it to the next one.

```js
// Grab all the elements
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

// Call a function as a key press handler that returns 
// a new function (the actual listener)
// that deals with the key presses. We do this
// because we want to keep a variable `index` to identify which 
// element in the collection we're on, and a closure
// (a function that hangs on to its local lexical environment
// when it's returned) is very convenient
document.addEventListener('keydown', handler(elements.length - 1), false);

// Set the initial element
elements[0].classList.add('active');

// So this is the handler that returns the closure.
// We pass in the array length, set up the index variable,
// and return a new listener function that deals with the key presses
function handler(arrayLength) {

  let index = 0;

  return function(e) {

    if (e.code === 'ArrowUp' && index > 0) {
      elements[index].classList.remove('active');
      --index;
      elements[index].classList.add('active');
    }

    if (e.code === 'ArrowDown' && index < arrayLength) {
      elements[index].classList.remove('active');
      ++index;
      elements[index].classList.add('active');
    }

  }

};
```

```css
.element { background: gray; width: 200px; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 1px; }
.active { background: red; }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
</section>
```

Additional documentation

- [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { // <-- add this wrapper
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

    if (element) {
    
      element.forEach(function(el, key){
        
         el.addEventListener('click', function () {
         
            el.classList.toggle("active");
            
             element.forEach(function(ell, els){
                 if(key !== els) {
                     ell.classList.remove('active');
                 }
             });
         });
      });
      document.body.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if(event.key=="ArrowUp" && document.getElementsByClassName("active").length > 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var active = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
          if(active.previousElementSibling)
            active.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
          active.classList.remove("active");
          return false;
        };
        if(event.key=="ArrowDown" && document.getElementsByClassName("active").length > 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var active = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
          if(active.nextElementSibling)
            active.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
          active.classList.remove("active");
          return false;
        }
        else if(event.key=="ArrowDown") {
          event.preventDefault();
          element[0].classList.add("active"); //If nothing is selected, use element[element.legth − 1] for the last element]
          return false;
        };
      };
    };
});
```

```css
.element{
  background: gray;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}

.element.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
  <div class="element">BOX</div>
</section>
```